# Getting a filtered array to save to a new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Making a calculator web app right now, and I want to save the  the filtered array to a new array " operatorsNDInputList " 
so that it saved the not duplicated operators to the array..

I need it to not run through the array till there has been atleast 2 inputs but then keep going even after there has been more than two inputs pushed the array?

Hope that makes sense maybe you'll be able to understand better if not after looking at the code:

```js
'use strict';

const input = document.querySelector('#input'), // input/output button
  numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.numbers div'), // number buttons
  operators = document.querySelectorAll('.operators div'), // operator buttons
  result = document.querySelector('#result'), // equal button
  clear = document.querySelector('#clear'); // clear button


let numberInput = []
let operatorsInput = []
let operatorsNDInputList = []

document.querySelectorAll('.numbers div').forEach(buttonPress => {
  buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    numberInput.push(parseInt(event.target.textContent));
    console.log(numberInput)
  });
});

document.querySelectorAll('.operators div').forEach(buttonPress => {
  buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    operatorsInput.push(event.target.textContent);
    console.log(operatorsInput)
  });
});

operatorsInput.filter((item, index) => {

  console.log(
    item, index, operatorsInput.indexOf(item), operatorsInput.indexOf(item) === index,
  );
  return operatorsInput.indexOf(item) === index
});
```

Comment: Please, read about [mcve], it doesn't seems that CSS and many HTML parts are relevant here, so it just "polutes" the question, try to re-create the issue using the topics from the link I sent

Comment: @CalvinNunes for sure, I figured people would need to see the HTML but then again I figure the people answering my question will understand the logic behind the Javascript.. thanks and sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the duplicates of the operators to stop appearing, using the set method.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.operators div').forEach(buttonPress => {
  buttonPress.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    operatorsInput.push(event.target.textContent);
    let noDuplicates = [...new Set(operatorsInput)];
    console.log(noDuplicates)
  });
});
```